# Python3: Is there a memory efficient way working with itertools.product

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for a way to overcome a huge memory issue.
I have about 100 lists, each containing an average of 10 elements.
And I need to create all possible combinations and work with them one by one (I don't need all at once).

Currently my code looks like this:

```
import itertools

l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = ['a','b','c']
l3 = ['a','b','c']

all_lists = [l1,l2,l3]
combination_list = [item for item in itertools.product(*all_lists)]

for c in combination_list:
    print(c) #do something with c
```

Sadly if I try to use more than 10 lists I get a memory error.
Any idea how I can overcome that memory issue?

Is there way saving the combinations one-by-one in a file and accessing them that way, too?

Edit: I should have said, that I need to access that combinations later on again, storing them in a dict as a key and assigning them a value.

Comment: Yes don't store them all at once, why did you create a list of them if you don't want them  all?

Comment: We strongly discourage editing questions which invalidate existing answers. You have completely changed the nature of this question, and in fact contradicted your original question. Both questions together read, "How do I store these in memory without storing them in memory?"

Comment: I do not need to access them all at once, but I need to work with them and sometimes add/edit an value for that combination.

Comment: @Ali I updated my answer. If you change your lists, the iterator will be reconstructed every time. But again, there is no reason to store every combination - it is very low cost to recreate it.

Comment: @Eli Sadoff: its 10000000000 ...

Comment: Every possible combination would be the number I gave. You have to do `sum(i C 1000, i = 1, 1000)`.

Comment: Sorry for bothering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, use the iterator straight up instead of putting it in a list.

```
for c in itertools.product(*all_lists):
    print(c) #do something with c
```

Looking at the doc for [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) you see it's just making an iterator.

#### EDIT

If you want to reuse the combinations later, you are better off just enumerating them again (so you don't have to store them).

```
combination_list = lambda: itertools.product(*all_lists)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. This is precisely what itertools is for. OP is forcing memory consumption with useless list comprehension `[item for item ...]`.

Comment: And if I need to use the combinations later on in my program again?

Comment: ...Then you can either call `itertools.product` again or store them all in memory, which as you have seen you do not have enough to do.